# Excel Files merging together vertically

Tags: python, excel, merge

i am trying to merge multiple excel files in one vertically they 5 same columns with different index columns i want them to be merged vertically without hiding the column
[image]

code i used to convert csv to excel:

```
import pandas as pd
import os
from openpyxl import load_workbook

def create_pivot_tables(input_folder, output_folder):
    # Get a list of all subfolders in the input folder
    subfolders = [subfolder for subfolder in os.listdir(input_folder) if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(input_folder, subfolder))]

    for subfolder in subfolders:
        # Get the path of the current subfolder
        subfolder_path = os.path.join(input_folder, subfolder)

        # Get a list of all CSV files in the subfolder
        csv_files = [file for file in os.listdir(subfolder_path) if file.endswith('.csv')]

        # Initialize an empty list to store the pivot tables
        pivot_tables = []

        for csv_file in csv_files:
            # Assuming you have already loaded the DataFrame 'df' from the CSV file
            df = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(subfolder_path, csv_file))
            new_column_names = {
                'Year of VISIT_DATE (OOS_ANNUAL_SUMMARY)': 'Year',
                'Month of VISIT_DATE (OOS_ANNUAL_SUMMARY)': 'Month',
                'Measure Names': ''
            }

            # Rename the columns using the dictionary
            df.rename(columns=new_column_names, inplace=True)

            # Drop rows containing 'All' in any cell
            df = df[~df.apply(lambda row: 'All' in row.values, axis=1)]

            # Extract the index column names by removing the columns used in the pivot_table function
            index_columns = list(set(df.columns) - set(['', 'Year', 'Month', 'Measure Values']))

            pivot_table_df = df.pivot_table(values='Measure Values', 
                                            index=index_columns,
                                            columns=['', 'Year', 'Month'],
                                            aggfunc='first')  # Use 'first' to select the first value if there are duplicates.

            # Append the pivot table to the list
            pivot_tables.append(pivot_table_df)

        # Save the pivot tables to separate Excel files in the subfolder
        for i, pivot_table_df in enumerate(pivot_tables):
            output_file_name = os.path.splitext(csv_files[i])[0] + '_pivot_table.xlsx'
            output_file_path = os.path.join(subfolder_path, output_folder, output_file_name)

            # Check if there is an existing file to append to
            if os.path.exists(output_file_path):
                with pd.ExcelWriter(output_file_path, mode='a') as writer:
                    # Load the existing workbook and worksheet
                    book = load_workbook(writer.path)
                    writer.book = book
                    writer.sheets = dict((ws.title, ws) for ws in book.worksheets)

                    # Add empty rows before appending the data
                    writer.sheets[list(writer.sheets.keys())[0]].insert_rows(0, 2)

                    # Append the pivot table to the existing file
                    pivot_table_df.to_excel(writer, startrow=2, index=True, header=False)
            else:
                # Save the pivot table to a new Excel file
                pivot_table_df.to_excel(output_file_path, index=True)


input_folder = 'CSV'
output_folder = 'output'
create_pivot_tables(input_folder, output_folder)
```

code i used to merge excel in one:

```
import os
import pandas as pd

def merge_excel_files(input_folder, output_file):
    # Get a list of all Excel files in the input folder
    excel_files = [file for file in os.listdir(input_folder) if file.endswith('.xlsx')]

    # Initialize an empty list to store the DataFrames
    dfs = []

    for excel_file in excel_files:
        # Load each Excel file into a DataFrame
        df = pd.read_excel(os.path.join(input_folder, excel_file))

        # Add an empty row at the end of the DataFrame
        df = df.append(pd.Series(), ignore_index=True)

        # Append the DataFrame to the list
        dfs.append(df)

    # Concatenate the DataFrames vertically with an empty row in between
    merged_df = pd.concat(dfs, ignore_index=True)

    # Save the merged DataFrame to a new Excel file
    merged_df.to_excel(output_file, index=False)


input_folder = 'CSV\AL_KABEER_OSA_PLANO_ACCOUNT_MANAGER_SUMMARY'
output_file = 'merged_output.xlsx'
merge_excel_files(input_folder, output_file)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n2ir0.png)
```

[image]

i am expecting this output in picture where data should drop below these columns
as i have different columns like account manager , category and other files and station managre extra max columns would go to 3 on left side rest 5 will stay the same